# Group By LINQ Query result to DataGridView

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I Am new to EF and LINQ (just a couple of days of reading and exercising for a preparations into a switch from stored procs and ADO). Im trying to bind my query result into a GridView but I don't get it how to bind all the field result with the group by. Please give me some of your inputs which will be a Big Help! :)

This is so far from what I've done but it only binds the group key. Im trying to bind the result with a fields consists of: FirstName, City and the GrpCount as Count for each customers belong into a group. I also tried some Anonimous Types to pick the fields that Im trying to be visible into the Grid but so far not worked since I am not yet familiar from it.

```
var query = from cust in db.Customers
            group cust by cust.City into grp
            orderby grp.Key
            select grp;

dataCustomer.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

The result must be something similar to:

```
    Name || City || Count

    name1   city1       1
    name2   city2       2
    name3   city2       2
```

Using nested foreach Statement, I can easily produced that result using FormatString() then passed to a messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

this will work perfectly :

```
var query = from cust in db.Customers
            group cust by cust.City into grp
            orderby grp.Key
            from item in grp 
            select item;
dataCustomer.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why your code solves the problem.